# Unifying different theories of integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces

Having a few theories of integration in mind (not just Riemann and Lebesgue, see also [Darboux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral#Definition) and [Cauchy integral defined here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52708/why-should-one-still-teach-riemann-integration)), I am thinking about how those integration theories are related. To do this, let me invent the following definition.

**Definition.** An integration theory on an open set $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a tuple $(E,T)$ where $E$ is a subspace of the vecctor space $\mathbb R^X$ (Space of all real-valued functions on $X$) and $T$ is a linear functional $E\to \mathbb R$, satisfying the following properties:

1. The indicator function of every open/closed/half-open interval ($\mathbf 1_{(a,b)},\mathbf 1_{(a,b]}$ and so on) are in $E$.
2. $T(\mathbf 1_{(a,b)})=b-a$.
3. $T$ is continuous with respect to the supremum norm. In other words, $Tf_n\to Tf$ whenever $f_n$ converges **uniformly** to $f$ in $X$. This is, of course, only need to be true for $f\in E$.

This definition is not necessarily satisfactory because it is not immediate that some other important properties of integrals are guaranteed. For example, Riemann and Lebesgue integrals defines $L^p$ seminorms on certain class of functions, but I am not sure if every "integration theory" in the sense described above defines a norm. For the moment, let assume that an integration theory defines an $L^p$ seminorm (possibly after refining the definition).

Let's further define $(F,U)$ to be a sub-theory if $F$ is a subspace of $E$
and $U=T$ on $F$. Or we can say $(E,T)$ is an extension of $(F,U)$. So Riemann's theory is a subtheory of Lebesgue's theory. We can say an extension is complete if the norm makes $E$ a complete metric space.

Note that each integration theory is associated with an $L^p$ seminorm. If we put those norms together, we can analyse whether one theory is dense in another, and things like that.

I am sorry if this question is too vague. The questions is: are we going to get some useful results if we continue this way of thinking? Are there any similar theories that unifies different types of integrals (Lebesgue, Riemann, etc) in the sense described above?

Comment: Did you hear about Daniell integral?

Comment: @Botond Oh that's interesting. Yes I am thinking about an axiomatic approach.

Comment: And I think $T(1_{(a,b)})=b-a$ is not essential, because it just happens to hold in Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral with Lebesgue-measure. But when you pick, for example, the counting measure on $[0,+\infty)$, the indicator functions of the non-empty open intervals won't even be integrable.

Comment: Also, the indicator function of the real line is not Lebesgue integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Also, let $f_n=\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$. $f_n$ converges to zero uniformly, because $\lVert f_n \rVert_{\infty}=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$, but it's Lebesgue integral is $1$ for all $n$, hence $Tf_n \not\to Tf=0$.

Comment: @Botond Yes, maybe I should have added ''uniform convergence on a compact set".

Comment: @Botond If we do not require $T(1_{(a,b)})=b-a$, then it is pretty much just a linear functional, continuous in some sense.

Comment: As I mentioned before, not all of the integrals have that identity, but this identity is a good "starting point" to get the area under the curve interpetation of the integral. In the case of Daniell integral, picking the step functions as elementary functions (i.e. linear combination of indicator functions), will result the Lebesgue integral (with rhe Lebesgue measure). But personally, asking for the indicator functions to be in $E$ is "too much", because "a lot of" our vector spaces does not contain them (for example the vector space od polynomials with degree at most $n$ or $C^n$.